# how to fix keyerror in python

Tags: python, mysql

How can i fix this?

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, **employe_data):
        self.employee_id = employe_data['employee_id']
        self.first_name = employe_data['first_name']
        self.last_name = employe_data['last_name']
        self.born = employe_data['born']
        self.photo = employe_data['photo']
        self.moto = employe_data['moto']
        self.position_company = employe_data['position_company']


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        employee = []
        if self.first_name is not None:
            employee.append(self.first_name)
        if self.last_name is not None:
            employee.append(self.last_name)
        
        return " ".join(employee)
```

error name is

> self.first_name = employe_data['first_name']
> KeyError: 'first_name'

also in mysql, row is called `first_name`, thanks in forward

Comment: We need to see what `employe_data` is; in other words, what you're passing to the `__init__` method.

Comment: In __init__ debug (by printing or through debugger) what key-values you are really getting in. first_name key is definitely missing, else, KeyError would not have occurred.